# replace UIlabel in place of UIImageView without deletion of constraints in interfacebuilder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I have a `xib` where I have a `UIImageView`. I have already setup constraints for `UIImageview` with other `Labels`. Now I want `UILabel` in-place of `UIImageView`.
Is it possible to replace `UIImageView` with `UILabel` without removing the `contraints` in `interface builder` ?

Comment: No it is not possible. You have to reapply constraints after you add the UILabel, or you can follow the suggested way by Kubba!

Answer (score 1):

You can place both UIImageView and UILabel on xib and toggle visibility when needed.